# как в mapBox сделать cluster для точек на карте?

Tags: xcode, swift3, cluster, mapbox

Mapbox SDK
Swift 3
имеется масив с точками на карте, как сделать кластер для точек с масива?
по примерам и документации не могу добавить так как там берут точки с JSON
[image]

сдесь достаю масив аннотейшн

```
/////[GET ANNOTATIONS]////////
func pin (_ str: String = "All") -> [MGLAnnotation] {

    self.places.removeAll()



    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = CoreDataManager.instance.managedObjectContext
    let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "DictPlace")

    if str != "All" {


        fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category == %@", str)
    }

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetch.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    fetch.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    let fetchResults = try! context.fetch(fetch)



    let ct = fetchResults.count


    for row in 0...ct-1 {
        let data: NSManagedObject = fetchResults[row] as! NSManagedObject


        let placeElement = data as! DictPlace

        places.append(placeElement)

    }

    for place in places {

        let location = place.loc
        let annotation = PlaceAnnotation()
        annotation.myPlace = place

        annotation.title = place.name
        annotation.subtitle = place.rating


        let latitude = NSString(string: (location.latitude)!).doubleValue
        let longitude = NSString(string: (location.longitude)!).doubleValue

        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (latitude), longitude: (longitude))
        arrayPins.append(annotation)
    }

    return arrayPins
}


func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {
     ВОТ ТУТ НЕ ЗНАЮ КАК ПОДСТАВИТЬ МОЙ МАСИВ С ТОЧКАМИ МЕСТО URL на файл JSON
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ports", ofType: "geojson")!)

    let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "clusteredPorts",
                                url: url,
                                options: [.clustered: true, .clusterRadius: icon.size.width])
    style.addSource(source)


    // Use a template image so that we can tint it with the `iconColor` runtime styling property.
    style.setImage(icon.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), forName: "icon")

    // Show unclustered features as icons. The `cluster` attribute is built into clustering-enabled source features.
    let ports = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "ports", source: source)
    ports.iconImageName = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: "icon")
    ports.iconColor = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor.darkGray.withAlphaComponent(0.9))
    ports.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K != YES", "cluster")
    style.addLayer(ports)

    // Color clustered features based on clustered point counts.
    let stops = [
        20:  MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor.lightGray),
        50:  MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor.orange),
        100: MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor.red),
        200: MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor.purple)
    ]

    // Show clustered features as circles. The `point_count` attribute is built into clustering-enabled source features.
    let circlesLayer = MGLCircleStyleLayer(identifier: "clusteredPorts", source: source)
    circlesLayer.circleRadius = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: NSNumber(value: Double(icon.size.width) / 2))
    circlesLayer.circleOpacity = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: 0.75)
    circlesLayer.circleStrokeColor = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.75))
    circlesLayer.circleStrokeWidth = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: 2)
    circlesLayer.circleColor = MGLSourceStyleFunction(interpolationMode: .interval,
                                                      stops: stops,
                                                      attributeName: "point_count",
                                                      options: nil)
    circlesLayer.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == YES", "cluster")
    style.addLayer(circlesLayer)

    // Label cluster circles with a layer of text indicating feature count. Per text token convention, wrap the attribute in {}.
    let numbersLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "clusteredPortsNumbers", source: source)
    numbersLayer.textColor = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor.white)
    numbersLayer.textFontSize = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: NSNumber(value: Double(icon.size.width) / 2))
    numbersLayer.iconAllowsOverlap = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: true)
    numbersLayer.text = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: "{point_count}")
    numbersLayer.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == YES", "cluster")
    style.addLayer(numbersLayer)

    // Add a tap gesture for zooming in to clusters or showing popups on individual features.
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:))))
}

func mapViewRegionIsChanging(_ mapView: MGLMapView) {
    showPopup(false, animated: false)
}

func handleTap(_ tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if tap.state == .ended {
        let point = tap.location(in: tap.view)
        let width = icon.size.width
        let rect = CGRect(x: point.x - width / 2, y: point.y - width / 2, width: width, height: width)

        let clusters = mapView.visibleFeatures(in: rect, styleLayerIdentifiers: ["clusteredPorts"])
        let ports = mapView.visibleFeatures(in: rect, styleLayerIdentifiers: ["ports"])

        if clusters.count > 0 {
            showPopup(false, animated: true)
            let cluster = clusters.first!
            mapView.setCenter(cluster.coordinate, zoomLevel: (mapView.zoomLevel + 1), animated: true)
        } else if ports.count > 0 {
            let port = ports.first!

            if popup == nil {
                popup = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40))
                popup!.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.9)
                popup!.layer.cornerRadius = 4
                popup!.layer.masksToBounds = true
                popup!.textAlignment = .center
                popup!.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
                popup!.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
                popup!.textColor = UIColor.black
                popup!.alpha = 0
                view.addSubview(popup!)
            }

            popup!.text = (port.attribute(forKey: "name")! as! String)
            let size = (popup!.text! as NSString).size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: popup!.font])
            popup!.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height).insetBy(dx: -10, dy: -10)
            let point = mapView.convert(port.coordinate, toPointTo: mapView)
            popup!.center = CGPoint(x: point.x, y: point.y - 50)

            if popup!.alpha < 1 {
                showPopup(true, animated: true)
            }
        } else {
            showPopup(false, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

func showPopup(_ shouldShow: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    let alpha: CGFloat = (shouldShow ? 1 : 0)
    if animated {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) { [unowned self] in
            self.popup?.alpha = alpha
        }
    } else {
        popup?.alpha = alpha
    }
}
```

Comment: Каким примерам и в чем проблема с JSON? Приведите ссылки, что делали, что вызывает затруднение.

Comment: @VAndrJ https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/clustering/

Comment: @VAndrJ у меня нету такого json 
а есть только масив точек
вот такого типа
но примерно штук 200 и все разные
["lat": 50.00000,
"lng": 30.0000, "lat": 50.00000,
"lng": 30.0000]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените там где оставили комментарий что не знаете на:

```
func getPoint() -> MGLPointFeature {
    let point = MGLPointFeature()
    point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(arc4random_uniform(75000000)) / 1000000, longitude: Double(arc4random_uniform(75000000)) / 1000000)
    return point
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {
    //let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ports", ofType: "geojson")!)
    var shape = [MGLShape]()
    for _ in 0...1000 {
        shape.append(getPoint())
    }
    let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "clusteredPorts", features: shape, options: [.clustered: true, .clusterRadius: icon.size.width])
```

Посмотрите результат, подставляйте свои точки вместо рендомных.

Comment: как-то не понимаю
оно падает на identifier: "clusteredPorts",
и не понимаю как можно подставить данные с масива func pin (_ str: String = "All") -> [MGLAnnotation] в [MGLShape]

Comment: в pin() я достаю с CoreData масив точек [MGLAnnotation]
и их нужно поместить в кластер